# How to restrict content from Users with Specific roles in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to hide ads for logged in user (subscribers). im using a plugin called "private" that generates shortcodes. i found the code i should use but dont know how to put it in my single.php. My single post is custom made so i cant use the rich editor.

the one i want to use...

`[private role=”subscriber”]Content goes here[/private]`

and i want to put this code in the middle position of my short code.

```
<div id="M589567ScriptRootC925056"></div>
<script src="https://jsc.adskeeper.co.uk/a/n/anime-tv.fun.925056.js" async></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what we need. When you are ready, you can update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use `[private]` short codes to hide `divs` or ads in your case from logged in users.

Just use WordPress native `current_user_can()` function to target specific user roles like this in PHP file

```
if (current_user_can('subscriber')) {

   //Hide something

} else {

   //Show Something

}
```

You can do something if you want to hide something from all logged in users

```
if (is_user_logged_in) {

   //Hide something

} else {

   //Show Something

}
```

This code goes into your working `php` file or active theme `function.php`

Comment: @ShawnStolting You are welcome! Glad that i could helped you. Thanks

Comment: i have another problem. It came when i updated the plugin called ithemes. 

The error says "ALTER command denied to user............." 

Could you help ?

Comment: @ShawnStolting I have never used this plugin. But this will help: [Click here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ithemes-security-setup-error/) for the official answer from the plugin author regarding this issue.

Comment: @ShawnStolting No worries! happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

There could be a much easier and versatile way to achieve that.

1. create a function to have the user role appear as a body class

   ```
    function get_user_role() {
        global $current_user;
        $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
        $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
        return $user_role;
    }

    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) {
        $classes[] = get_user_role();
        return $classes;
    }
   ```
2. add a specific CSS class to posts, blocks, pages that you want to filter and  declare display: none; or display: block; accordingly

Ex. I want to show a post to editors and authors but hide it to visitors, subscribers and contributors. So I add the class 'post-filter' to the post and add these lines to style.css

```
.post-filter, 
.subscriber .post-filter, 
.contributor .post-filter {display: none;}

.editor .post-filter,
.author .post-filter,
.administrator .post-filter {display: block;}
```

And that's it.