# Make Wordpress Custom sidebar visible only for specific customer role?

Tags: wordpress

I have created my custom sidebar, that i apply for selected pages only. Now want to make this sidebar hidden or not visible for users with selected role. This is my custom sidebar function that i use:

```
function my_custom_sidebar() {
register_sidebar(
    array (
        'name' => __( 'Sidebar', 'your-theme-domain' ),
        'id' => 'custom-side-bar',
        'description' => __( 'Custom Sidebar', 'your-theme-domain' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-content">',
        'after_widget' => "</div>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )
);
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_custom_sidebar' );
```

Someone to help me?

Comment: I have answered a same question here: [How to restrict content from Users with Specific roles in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294829/how-to-restrict-content-from-users-with-specific-roles-in-wordpress/62295677#62295677)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict content from Users with Specific roles in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294829/how-to-restrict-content-from-users-with-specific-roles-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, this is the basis of only allowing users with specific capabilities to do something...

```
if ( current_user_can( 'customer' ) {
   // your code
}
```

**Reference:**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/